# Can the same partition be used for both plain text swap and encrypted swap?

Tags: encryption, swap

In Natty swap does not work. It has been corrupted and even gparted does not recognize its type. Maybe it is due Oneiric daily that I installed in the same computer and it uses the same partition as encrypted swap. (I have encrypted /home folder in both distributions.) Can Oneiric use this as encrypted swap, if I repartition the partition as linux-swap and use it unencrypted in Natty?

Answer (score 1):

See the attached link as I think it might be a solution that you are looking for.

[EncryptedFilesystemHowto3](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto3)